# nodejs and static html on one domain and one port

Tags: node.js

I have static html website that sends AJAX requests to nodejs scripts. I don't want to send crossdomain requests, so I want static website and nodejs work on same port and same domain. How can I do that?
Now my nodejs works on localhost:1337 and my static website works on denwer localhost/mywebsite and AJAX requests don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on which framework you're using. With `express`, you can set up all the dynamic endpoints of your application and also:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

This will serve the `/static` directory of your `nodejs` project alongside the rest of the endpoints.

Note:

- Other frameworks have similar setups. Google for `nodejs <your framework> serving static files`.
- Doing it *without* a framework is non-trivial.